# POI method WorkbookFactory.create performance issue

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read an xlsx file using Apache POI, but when I call the method WorkbookFactory.create, it is not responding and no exception is thrown. The file is not that big (40Mb).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DiversTest {

    @Test
    public void testLectureFichierExcel() throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException{
        File fichierSuivi = new File("in/resources/test.xlsx");
        InputStream inputXLS = new FileInputStream(fichierSuivi);
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputXLS);
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this work if you just pass the file into the WorkbookFactory? That should use less memory. `Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(ficherSuivi)'`

Comment: As quite clearly explained in the docs, [Don't use an InputStream if you have a File!](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

Comment: "is not responding" sounds like it could also be some sort of endless loop, can you post the output of "jstack <pid of your process>"?